403 Error on Creating BigQuery Jobs with a Service Account via Cloud Functions
I am using a service account to authorize a Google Cloud Function that executes a query in BigQuery. Despite the service account having the bigquery.jobs.create permission and appropriate table permissions in the project, I am encountering a 403 Access Denied error when trying to create a BigQuery job.
{
    "error": "403 POST https://bigquery.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/[PROJECT_ID]/jobs?prettyPrint=false: Access Denied: Project [PROJECT_ID]: User does not have bigquery.jobs.create permission in project [PROJECT_ID].\n\nLocation: US\nJob ID: [JOB_ID]\n",
    "success": false
}

Setup:
Cloud Function: Uses a service account for authentication.
Service Account Permissions: Includes bigquery.jobs.create.
BigQuery: The service account has permissions to access the relevant tables.
Unfortunately, I cannot share the full source code, but I can provide a conceptual overview of how the BigQuery interaction is implemented.
from google.cloud import bigquery

client = bigquery.Client(project='your-project-id')

query = """
SELECT name, count(*)
FROM `your-project-id.dataset.table`
GROUP BY name
"""

job = client.query(query)  # This line creates a BigQuery job

results = job.result()

for row in results:
    print(f"{row.name}: {row.count_}")

This simplified code should closely resemble what is being used in our project. If there are specific configurations or nuances in the actual implementation
Questions:
What could be causing the 403 Access Denied error given the service account appears to have the correct permissions?
Are there any project-level settings or other permissions that might affect the ability of the service account to create jobs in BigQuery?
Any insights or suggestions on what might be going wrong or how to troubleshoot this issue further would be greatly appreciated!
What I've tried:

Verified Service Account Permissions: I double-checked the service
account permissions in the Google Cloud IAM & Admin page to ensure
it includes roles/bigquery.jobUser, which encompasses the
bigquery.jobs.create capability.
Examined BigQuery Permissions: Reviewed the access control settings for the BigQuery datasets and tables involved to confirm that the service account has sufficient permissions (at least dataViewer roles on the relevant datasets).

I expected the Cloud Function to execute the query in BigQuery without any issues, given that the service account is supposed to have all necessary permissions to create and run BigQuery jobs.
Despite the correct setup, the function invocation results in a 403 Access Denied error, indicating that the service account supposedly does not have the bigquery.jobs.create permission. This is unexpected as the IAM roles and permissions appear to be configured correctly.

Please include (a) your code; (b) which Service Account is being used by the Cloud Function; (c) the roles associated with the Service Account. You describe what you have done but you don't show what you have done. Evidently at least one of your summarized steps is incorrect and so you need to show us what you've done so that we can help.

Can you share you Cloud Functions code?

"I've updated the question with a general overview of the code used to interact with BigQuery. Please check the updated question for more details!"

Are the Cloud Functions and BigQuery services in the same Google Project? Per the comments, you're missing salient (non-confidential) facts that would help us resolve the issue: the commands you're using to (a) create the Service Account; (b) the Cloud Functions deployment command etc.

It shouldn't affect the issue the project parameter is redundant in bigquery.Client(project='...') (see Client)
